# Cauchy problem, differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There's equation

$$\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) dx - x dy = 0$$

How do I solve it? I can't separate the variables in this one and the integrating factor method doesn't seem to work here as well. Could you give me any hint? Maybe it calls for a substitution, but I don't see it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$\displaystyle\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) dx - x dy\Rightarrow y'= \frac{y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x} \Rightarrow y'= \frac{y}{x}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$

and substitution $y = zx \Rightarrow y'=z'x+z \Rightarrow z'x+z = z + \sqrt{1+z^2}$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Write it as $$y'=\frac{y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}=f(x,y),~x\neq 0$$

Now see that $f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda^0 f(x,y)$. So the ODE is `H_m___us.`